# How to map objdump address to address in shared object

Tags: linux, assembly, shared-libraries, shared-objects

I am trying to patch a function. In objdump my program location shows an address which is greater than the file size. So I am assuming this is in a shared object. So how do I find the specific shared object and location of the procedure?

Comment: I'm not saying your wrong, but look again. Is it possible that your BSS is large, which may make addresses above it look abnormally large. Remember that BSS data is not actually stored in the executable. Instead, a reference defining how much space should be allocated is stored and the memory is typically allocated and zeroed when execution begins.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer thanks. Actually my problem was I forgot to subtract section address.

Comment: objdump will never show you anything from a file other than the one you're using it on. It might show you something from that file that refers to something in another file, but you won't show, for example, disassembled code from a shared object unless you're using objdump on that shared object.